# Converted VB code to C# but got error with list?

Tags: c#, vb.net, optimization

I got a script in VB that i wanted to convert to C# to use in a project.
But now i am kinda stuck and need your help.
Here is a part of the code:

```
If (Not selected) Then
    nbi.Content = True
    nbi.Childs(0).Selected = True
    finalSelectedItem = nbi.Childs(0)
    RaiseEvent SelectedItem(nbi.Childs(0))
End If
```

And when i used a online converter i got this back from it:

```
if (!selected)
{
    nbi.Content = true;
    nbi.Childs(0).Selected = true;
    finalSelectedItem = nbi.Childs(0);
    if (SelectedItem != null)
    {
        SelectedItem(nbi.Childs(0));
    }
}
```

But it gives me a error "Non-invocable member 'NavBarItem.Childs' cannot be used like a method.' at the line:

```
nbi.Childs(0).Selected = true;
```

The Childs list is like this in the class:

```
public List<NavBarItem> Childs;
```

Anyone know how to fix this as i have no clue how to do it :/

Thanks

Comment: if you are looking for indexed positions in C#, then you need to replace the `(0) with [0]`

Comment: It should be nbi.Childs[0].Selected = true; Same is true with other references to nbi.Childs. C# uses [] instead of () to access contents of lists and arrays.